# Cannot create connection from persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, cdi

I'm developing a basic CRUD application using CDI, JSF 2.1 with PrimeFaces 5.0 and PostgreSQL database managed through Hibernate JPA. Here's my pom.xml file (i created a CDI project using Eclipse and then added pom.xml):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>capacrm2</groupId>
    <artifactId>capacrm2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then, my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="crmPU">
        <!-- <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/Spring_DB</jta-data-source> -->
        <!-- -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> 

        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="public" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EHCacheProvider" />

            <!-- Hibernate parameters
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springdb" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="springusr" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="springusr" /> 
            -->
            <!-- JPA parameters -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="springusr" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="springusr" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've already used a container's datasource (JBoss 7.1) without problem as you can see in my persistence.xml (the java:jboss/datasources/Spring_DB line) and i know that for production is best to use container's connection pool, but right now I want to configure the connection inside persistence.xml , but i tried different ways without success.

Either using hibernate parameters or javax.persistence parameter I'm getting this error:

```
08:38:20,858 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."capacrm2.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."capacrm2.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "capacrm2.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider' not found
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:555)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deployPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:295)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.addPuService(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deploy(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

And if i remove persistence provider (using hibernate parameters) i get this:

```
08:39:57,743 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: crmPU
    ...]
08:39:57,806 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
08:39:57,806 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
08:39:57,806 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
08:39:57,806 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springdb]
08:39:57,806 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=springusr, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
08:39:57,822 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springdb
08:39:57,833 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
08:39:57,833 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
08:39:57,833 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
08:39:57,849 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
08:39:57,958 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
08:39:57,958 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
08:39:57,958 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springdb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:457) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]

08:39:57,974 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000299: Could not complete schema update: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springdb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:457) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
```

But if i switch to javax.persistence parameters (always without persistence provider) i get this:

```
08:41:24,386 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: crmPU
    ...]
08:41:24,449 WARN  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
08:41:24,464 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
08:41:24,464 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
08:41:24,480 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
08:41:24,480 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
08:41:24,589 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
08:41:24,589 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
08:41:24,589 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000299: Could not complete schema update: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:62) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:457) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
```

So, I've tried different combinations without success. What it could be?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. Are you deploying to JBoss AS/WildFly? If so, what's the point in duplicating the container's tasks at application level? Hibernate and postgres dependencies in your POM should be `provided`. JDBC drivers should be deployed as JARs or installed as modules.

Comment: Hi @hwellmann. I'm deploying to JBoss 7.1.1 on Windows. As you can see in my pom.xml (first code block) it has postgresql jdbc driver dependency (9.3-1102-jdbc41) and hibernate entitymanager (4.3.7 final) (i don't know if i'm missing something apart from that). Regards.

Comment: hmm are you sure its not a dependency problem , and all libraries are correct ? try using an older version of hibernate(ex 3.5.6) which is compatible with JPA v.1.0 or 1.1 and check the stack trace.

Comment: Did you deploy the postgres driver in EAP?

Answer (score 2):

You are deploying your application into JBoss that uses JTA and it already offers an XA `DataSource`.

You shouldn't be using "hibernate.connection.driver_class" because that's only meant for simple development use cases (never for production deployments).

If you were having a simple web application deployed into a web container (e.g. Tomcat) then you would have needed a **resource local** DataSource and a professional [connection pooling solution](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/) (e.g. HickariCP, DBCP2, BoneCP, C3P0).

But you are running an enterprise application inside an enterprise application server. These application servers favor JTA and so you should use the JTA DataSource offered by your application server. This way you can also benefit from the JTA Transaction Manager too.

So switch back to JTA transactions as JBoss likes it:

```
<persistence-unit name="crmPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/Spring_DB</jta-data-source>
```

As for the persistence provider, you could try this setting:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

You probably want to add also Hibernate transaction related properties:

hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
    hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class =org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
    jta.UserTransaction=java:jboss/datasources/Spring_DB